# zero terminated dynamic array as return value in Python

Tags: python, ctypes

From python I am trying to use c function that returns dynamically allocated zero terminated array of integers:

```c
int* my_func(void)
{
    int i;
    int *ret = (int*)malloc((LEN + 1) * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++) ret[i] = 1;
    ret[LEN] = 0

    return ret;
}
```

I need something like

```
from ctypes import *

l = cdll.LoadLibrary("lib.so")
my_func = l.my_func
my_func.restype = c_int * LEN

for x in my_func(): print x
```

The problem is that `LEN` is unknown in python code, I need to read the array till first zero element.

Comment: ctypes lets you set `restype` to an array, but it isn't doing what you think. It stores the returned pointer as the first item of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't really worked with ctypes yet, but what about:

```
from ctypes import *

l = cdll.LoadLibrary("lib.so")
my_func = l.my_func
my_func.restype = POINTER(c_int)

i = 0;
rv = my_func()
while rv[i]:
    print rv[i]
    i += 1
```

Comment: There might be a good reason for the c-implementation or not. E.g. in many cases `ctypes` are used with libraries you can't change anyway. Let the OP decide what makes sense...

Comment: If an array is desired, use `rv_array = cast(rv, POINTER(c_int * i))[0]`. You can set the [`errcheck`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes#ctypes._FuncPtr.errcheck) attribute of `my_func` to a function that returns the array.